# (nuub) #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

So i'm tring to do that basic bbdd and the last line, the foreing key, dosen't work I don't know why

```
CREATE TABLE tenda(
    codi TEXT(10) NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    adreca VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(codi(10))
) ENGINE = Innodb; 
CREATE TABLE plataforma(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = Innodb; 
CREATE TABLE videojoc(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    preu INT,
    idplataforma INT,
    coditenda TEXT(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(idPlataforma) REFERENCES PLATAFORMA(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(codiTenda(10)) REFERENCES TENDA(codi)
) ENGINE = Innodb;
```

error

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Short answer to the duplicate : you can't create a FK to a `TEXT` field

Comment: Okay i understand that i can't do a text(10) fK no ?

Comment: Ty @CID solved, changing text by varchar

Answer (score 0):

`codiTenda(10)` is not the field name, try `FOREIGN KEY(coditenda) REFERENCES TENDA(codi)` instead

Comment: Ty but then it says ,

#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'coditenda' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: *"ER_BLOB_KEY_WITHOUT_LENGTH: BLOB/TEXT column 'codiTenda' used in key specification without a key length"*

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE tenda(
    codi varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    adreca VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(codi(10))
) ENGINE = Innodb; CREATE TABLE plataforma(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = Innodb; CREATE TABLE videojoc(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    preu INT,
    idplataforma INT,
    coditenda varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(idPlataforma) REFERENCES PLATAFORMA(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(codiTenda) REFERENCES TENDA(codi)
) ENGINE = Innodb;